# Understanding the CPU time spent by process in user/kernel space

Tags: linux, cpu, x86, perf

I have an application which normally reports (`time` command reports):

```
real 1.59
user 1.42
sys 4.73
```

But when I load a shared library and run it then the time goes up quite high (`time` command reports):

```
real 28.51
user 106.22
sys 5.23
```

While a certain level of increase (2 to 4 times is reported on CentOS and Ubuntu -- which is as expected) in run is expected due to my shared library's work, the above
timing reported on Fedora 24 is too high.

I attempted to use `perf` which reported:

```
     255352.948615      task-clock:u (msec)       #    3.895 CPUs utilized
                 0      context-switches:u        #    0.000 K/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations:u          #    0.000 K/sec
            18,127      page-faults:u             #    0.071 K/sec
   664,852,184,198      cycles:u                  #    2.604 GHz                      (50.03%)
    19,323,811,463      stalled-cycles-frontend:u #    2.91% frontend cycles idle     (50.02%)
   578,178,881,331      stalled-cycles-backend:u  #   86.96% backend cycles idle      (50.02%)
   110,595,196,687      instructions:u            #    0.17  insn per cycle
                                                  #    5.23  stalled cycles per insn  (50.00%)
    28,361,633,658      branches:u                #  111.068 M/sec                    (50.01%)
       777,249,031      branch-misses:u           #    2.74% of all branches          (50.01%)

      65.564158710 seconds time elapsed
```

This appears to say that CPU is idle for plenty of time. But I am trying to find where that happens in the code (I have access to the entire source code both of my application and the shared library in question). I have also seen `perf report` which reports the time spent in percentages in functions/system calls. But I am interested in even finer level i.e. which line(s) in those functions so that I can understand why.

I appreciate it's not easy to provide any concrete advice given that I haven't provided much info on my application/shared library. I am only looking for suggestions/tools/ideas to figure out where the CPU is spending most of its time in the code (or being idle).

It's a Fedora 24 Linux/x86_64 with glibc 2.23 (both my application and shared library are compiled with gcc 6.1.1 and glibc 2.23).

Comment: You may want to try a profiler, such as [gprof](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Line_002dby_002dline.html#Line_002dby_002dline).

Comment: gprof also provides similar info to perf. I am right now using kcachegrind as the problem appears to be related to cache accesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This appears to say that CPU is idle for plenty of time.

Yes. Namely 87 % of all the time. But it does not mean that the processor does not work on other tasks and processes.

```
   664,852,184,198      cycles:u                  #    2.604 GHz                      (50.03%)
    19,323,811,463      stalled-cycles-frontend:u #    2.91% frontend cycles idle     (50.02%)
   578,178,881,331      stalled-cycles-backend:u  #   86.96% backend cycles idle      (50.02%)
   110,595,196,687      instructions:u            #    0.17  insn per cycle
```

Optimizing programs to better utilize the CPU and memory accesses it complex task and without any code, it is impossible to answer you in more detail.

Comment: Indeed. I am trying to identify the code parts to improve performance. Hence looking for tools/suggestions etc. So far, I found that the problem is due to bad cache accesses and CPUs constantly evicting caches resulting in bad performance.

Comment: Yes, that would be visible if you would have attached related events.